# Can electron, muon, and tau be the particles of the same field, just different fluctuations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model

The electron, muon, and tau somehow look the same, the only difference between them is their masses.

Can it be that they are the particles of the same field (not separate fields as an electron field, muon field, etc.), that they are just different fluctuations in this field?

(And the same in every other generation of particles.)

Comment: What makes you think they could be?

Comment: Only difference between them is their masses. They somehow look the same.

Comment: Well, it can be. It also can be that they originate from very different fields and this similarity is an artifact of the low energy construction (standard model is quite robust and can originate from wildly different models). We simply don't know right now. Do you want a review of current speculations?

Comment: I would like to.

Comment: And what i meant by the question is, does this idea violate any known law or something fundamental?